# Executar uma ação após cada caractere digitado em um EditText

Tags: android

É o seguinte, eu não estou conseguindo descobrir se o usuário digitou algo no `EditorText`. O que eu quero é que, cada caractere, numero ou letra que o usuário digitar, eu consiga realizar uma ação, logo depois.

Eu pesquisei bastante, fiz vários testes mas não consegui por eu ser novo em android. Pelo que eu entendi, existem 2 funções que TALVEZ eu possa usar:

Usando o **setOnEditorActionListener**:

```
private EditText valor;    

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     valor = findViewById(R.id.valor);

     valor.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
               if(digitou algo){
                  System.out.println("DIGITOU!");
               }
               return false;
           }
    });

}
```

Usando o **setOnKeyListener**:

```
valor.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
               if(digitou algo){
                  System.out.println("DIGITOU!");
               }
               return false;
         }
 });
```

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html):

```
valor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        System.out.println("DIGITOU!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Obrigado. Mais especificamente o `onTextChanged` pois cada caractere pressionado ele fará uma mesma ação. Abraço!